# How can I embed GraphQL inside an existing REST back end

Tags: java, spring, rest, graphql, backend

I have a legacy REST Java SpringBoot back end and I'd like to add GraphQL to it to filter large JSON results

I'm an old hand at REST but new to GraphQL. I've looked at samples and they seem to only provide details on creating an entirely new GraphQL back end.  I've tried adding a @Comonnent MyResolver extends GraphQLQueryResolver to my existing SpringBoot app, but it's not getting called (no surprise, not sure why it would be).  Can I add GraphQL "endpoints" along with my existing @RestController endpoints in the same SpringBoot app?

Another idea. I'm thinking is that I might simply pass an additional parameter via normal REST call in the body, key: "GraphQL" and Value: "GraphQL query".  My back end will pull up the usual large JSON result from storage.  Then using a GraphQLResolver, run the back end data and query.  Finally I'd send the result back to the caller.  Does this make sense?  This strikes me as a sensible migration pattern that anyone would use to go from existing REST to GraphQL without a big endpoint rewrite.

Comment: I suspect this is my answer...

https://dzone.com/articles/dynamically-filter-json-with-jackson-and-squiggly

Comment: Be cautious, GraphQL is not REST.

As for having a or multiple GraphQL endpoints along REST, it should definitely work. GraphQL spring boot is just creating a servlet exposed on a given path that you specify and only that. There is no technical limitations in doing so